# split a state into values in excel - how to please

Tags: excel, split, components, states

if I have a state 48456 among others where 11111 to nnnnnn states exist, how can I split the (or any number of) state in excel from its one cell into 5 new cells containing in order the results of the state in question  eg

```
A1           B1          C1            D1           E1         F1
48586 into    4            8            4            5           6
```

Thank you.

PS I have a lot of states to split into separate cells.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
=--MID($A1,COLUMN(A:A),1)
```

in B1 and copy over and down the list.

[image]